# styled-components toggle classes

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

this.state.checkBool is `true` / `false`

The HTML structure like this, toggle `class1` and `class2`

```
<div class='common class1'>
<div class='common class2'>
```

css looks like

```
common {
  display: block;
  background: grey;
}

.class1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 1px;
  right: auto;
  top: 2px;
  background: blue;
}


.class2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: auto;
  top: 2px;
  right: 30px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

The styled component

```
const Wrapper = styled.div`
  display: block;
  background: grey;

  // Should this part use props to check true or false?

  ${prosp => } 
`
```

I am stuck on how to toggle classes

```
<Wrapper toggle={this.state.checkBool ? class1 :class2 }/>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to keep all the CSS in the `styled.div` and use the `toggle` prop to decide which CSS you should use for the component depending on its value.

**Example**

```js
const Wrapper = styled.div`
  display: block;
  background: grey;
  ${props => {
    if (props.toggle) {
      return `
        position: absolute;
        left: 1px;
        right: auto;
        top: 2px;
        background: blue;
      `;
    } else {
      return `
        position: absolute;
        left: auto;
        top: 2px;
        right: 30px;
        background: yellow;
      `;
    }
  }}
`;

class App extends React.Component {
  state = { checkBool: false };

  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ checkBool: true });
    }, 1000);
  }

  render() {
    return <Wrapper toggle={this.state.checkBool}> Foo </Wrapper>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/styled-components/dist/styled-components.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```